# Node.js Serve-static not working

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having some trouble with routing and serving static files.

My directory structure is like this:

```
app/    
--app.js
—-public/
  —-js/
    —-main.js
—-views/
  —-pages/
    —-index.jade
```

This is how I've set up my server:

app.js

```
var express = require('express')
var path = require('path')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')
var publicPath = path.join(__dirname,'..','public');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000
var app = express()

app.set('views', './views/pages')
app.set('view engine', 'jade')
app.use('/public', serveStatic(publicPath));

app.listen(port)

console.log("port is " + port)


app.get('/', function(req, res) {  
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'index',
        })
})
```

index.jade

```
doctype
html
    head
        meta(charset="utf-8")
        title index
        script(src="/public/js/main.js”)
    body
        h1=title
```

But this is what happens when I visit the index:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/public/js/main.js 404 (Not Found)
```

How do I set up the "serve-static" part to work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you are passing the wrong parameter to it.

correct example for serving static files from different directory would be

```
This example shows a simple way to search through multiple directories. Files are look for in public-optimized/ first, then public/ second as a fallback.

var express = require('express')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')

var app = express()

app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + '/public-optimized'))
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + '/public'))
app.listen(3000)
```

check out the docs for more options https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static

Comment: check your public path...  try path.join(__dirname,'../public')

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove public from the path.

```
script(src="/js/main.js”)
```

You're telling the server static resources are served from the public folder.